# WPF panel that can be oriented vertically, but fill parent container

Tags: wpf, responsive-design, orientation, panel, stackpanel

Basically I need a `stackpanel` that will fill its parent and where the children will fill the panel.

I'm currently using a `grid` designed to fill a rectangular shape which is wider than it is tall. I want my design to be reactive so that if the rectangular container is made taller than it is wide, then my child elements are arranged vertically and still fill the container.

A wrap panel would not work (I don't think) as I need the orientation to be all or nothing; either the child elements are all oriented horizontally, or all vertically.

I'm thinking I should replace the grid with a dockpanel, with each item docked either Left (for horizontal stacking), or top (for vertical stacking), but how do I achieve an even stretch on my child elements?

Comment: I'm finding this a little difficult to parse. Are you able to provide some approximate XAML or doodles which might clear things up? It would be particularly useful to see the code you have now, with indications of where you believe changes should be made.

Comment: Imagine 3 roughly square controls oriented horizontally next to each other and filling a parent container evenly. Now resize the container so that it is tall and thin - I want the 3 roughly square containers to align vertically top to bottom, whilst still filling the parent. Basically I want exactly what a stack panel would do if you changed the orientation property, but I need the child squares to fill the panel completely.

Answer (score 1):

For a panel to fill another panel a good way is to use `DockPanel`

Here is a Sample that works for me:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <DockPanel Dock="Top"></DockPanel>
            <DockPanel></DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

The first inner `DockPanel` will stick to the top and the second one will fill the rest of parent panel.

Note: None of both parent and child `DockPanel` should not be in a `WrapPanel`.